# How to implement a loop logic in a Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, invokeandwait

My title is somewhat cryptic but I couldn't come up with a clear one.

First, two code snippets to establish a point of reference (hopefully I have no typos):

Input with `Scanner`

```
'''
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i=0; i<10; ++ i)  {
  System.out.print("Please input a value:");
  String answer = sc.next();
  // do something with this string
}  
...
```

Input with `JOptionPane`:

```
...
for (int i=0; i<10; ++ i) {
   String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a value");
   // do something with this string
{
```

So, in the above samples we're asking a user to enter a value a **fixed number of times**.  How can I implement the same kind of functionality in a **Swing** application?

I have no problem creating a `JFrame` with `JPanel` (as its content pane) and adding `JLabel` (with prompt) and `JTextField` to this panel.  I can also create `ActionListener` for the text field which `ActionPerformed` method to retrieve the value and process it.  String processing is not a long-running task so I do not believe I will need a separate worker thread.

Since we can't really *force* user to do anything, I plan to use `javax.swing.Timer` to ensure a timely response.

What I do not understand is how to implement the loop or any other form of control to ensure that a user enters (and the program retrieves) the value the exact number of times. How do I inject such logic into an event-driven system?

Once I set-up the GUI part and submit its instance to be invoked on EDT I seem to be relinquishing all control.

Do I initially submit my text field with `setEditable` set to `false` and then create a loop that will `invokeAndWait` a `Runnable` to enable the edit (and disable it back in the `ActionPerformed`)?

Please point me into the right direction.

Comment: Use a `JOptionPane` to hold the flow, till user enters something to proceed with. Is there a problem with the second approach, that you defined? Please elaborate on that.

Comment: Do you not want to use a dialog for some reason? You can put basically anything inside one and modality is hard to pass up for certain things. With the counting--bottom line is you probably have to write some kind of object for this.

Comment: I do not want to use `JOptionPane` and want to use `JTextField`.  I'm creating quite a complex GUI screen for a math game.

Answer (score 5):

Well it depends on how you want to achieve it...

### You could...

Provide the required number of fields (10 in your example) and a `JButton`, so that until all the fields are filled out, clicking the button will simply provide the user with a message and re-focus the invalid field...

### You could...

Provide the user with a single field (and label) and button.  Until they fill out the field, pressing the button prompts them and re-focuses the field.

When the user fills out the required information and clicks the button, you increment a counter, reset the field and carry on until your counter reaches it's limit...

### You could...

Use a `JTable` which has only one column and five rows...this is simplified (depending on your perspective) solution to the first solution...

Comment: My requirement is that entry is completed when a user presses `Enter` or the time expires (Timer fires an event) whatever comes first.  No additional control buttons.

Comment: Okay, second option, no button and action listener on field...Hope your user knows how to move to the next "question" ... `JOptionPane` has buttons BTW ;)

Comment: Only one text field can be open for entry at a time and it should have the focus.

Comment: Yes, it seems that button-less 2nd option could work.